# A small function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

```
def square_digits(num):
    result = []
    if num > 0:
        result.append(num%10)
        num= num//10
    list = ''
    for i in result:
        list += str(i**2)
    return int(list)
```

This is a small function I want to square every digit of a number, just like if '991'runs through the function, '81811' will come out. But I always get wrong answer '81'.Can anyone figure out what happened?

Comment: check `result` before starting the `for`. I think, you probably want the `num//10` part in a loop like in replacing `for` by `while`.

Comment: It works if I change `if` to`while` to some extent, I always consider if statement same as while statement before.

Comment: Avoid using `list` as a variable name; it is the name of the built-in `list()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `if` by `while` otherwise it only computes the square of the first digit:

```
 def square_digits(num):
    result = []
    while num > 0:
        result.append(num%10)
        num= num//10
    list = ''
    for i in result:
        list += str(i**2)
    return int(list)
```

Comment: edited for reversing before squaring the array else it will print wrong answer

Answer (score 0):

following is the corrected answer posting as edits are not accepted on previous answer(don't take it otherwise)

```
 def square_digits(num):
    result = []
    while num > 0:
        result.append(num%10)
        num= num//10
    list = ''
    result.reverse()
    for i in result:
        list += str(i**2)
    return int(list)
```